# TIME_FORMAT Returns NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a time stored in mysql, the column is set as time, so it reads `13:16:00`. When I try to run

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT ('alarm_time', '%H:%i) FROM `Alarm`;
```

I get a `NULL`, I am trying to get a result of `13:06`.

Comment: Remove the quotes around alarm_time, or you will extract hour and minute  from that string

Comment: If `alarm_time` is the field name - use backticks.

Comment: @StefanoZanini, yup that fixed it thank you, I am disappointed in myself. I made a mistake like that.  Well Off topic a little bit, but when I use to compare time, anyway to have it = to the time within a min?

Comment: @StefanoZanini do you mind putting an answer so I can mark yours as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes around `alarm_time` are causing that to be interpreted as a string. If you remove them, or surround them with backticks,  it will be interpreted as the table's column, which contains a date. 
These should both work

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT (alarm_time, '%H:%i' ) FROM `Alarm`;
```

or

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT (`alarm_time`, '%H:%i' ) FROM `Alarm`;
```

Regarding the question about comparison you asked in the comments, if I understood correctly you can do that with something like

```
yourDate between SUBTIME(yourOtherDate, '00:00:30') and ADDTIME(yourOtherDate, '00:00:30')
```

or any other interval

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use `left(value,position)`.

`select left(alarm_time,5) from Alarm;` with correct schema name and backticks where ever required should suffice.

The function is self explanatory in its syntax :)

Comment: @Vlad: It'll be helpful in such cases as well as in more complex formats. Let us assume you need just the last 5 digits of a 10-digit contact number to gather some location info. You can simply query `select right(mobile,5) from blah` and you would get the last 5 digits. A combination of `left` and `right` will bail you out in cases where you would need the `nth` part from a string / number.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
select time_format(alarm_time,'%h:%m') as alarm_time
  from alarm;
```